# When introducing an initialism for the first time in a paper, but the noun is possessive, do I make the initialism possessive as well?

Tags: writing-style, possessives, acronyms, initialisms, formatting

E.g.,

> Mobile network operator's (MNO's) networks are overloaded.

Or

> Mobile network operator's (MNO) networks are overloaded.

Comment: What style guide does your field use? (APA, MLA, Chicago, AMA, IEEE, etc.) Does that style guide have anything to say on the subject? If you would clarify your question a bit to highlight context, you may get a better answer.

Comment: Do yourself and your readers a favour. Rephrase to *The networks of mobile network operators (MNOs) are overloaded.* That way you won't need *either* of those clumsy possessive apostrophes.

Comment: Incorrect use of apostrophe. MNOs (plural), not MNO’s, which would be possessive. Get that right first!

Comment: I've seen it both ways but, in my opinion for whatever it's worth, omitting the possessive looks cleaner.

Comment: @David, this refers to the networks that belong to the operator; "operator's" is possessive.

Comment: @Brady, how many operators are you talking about?

Comment: @mRotten Since he isn't using a definite article, I would presume multiple MNOs, therefore it should have a possessive but after the s. MNOs'. This looks HORRIBLE though so I would suggest rephrasing.

Comment: There's a third option (not counting avoiding the issue by rephrasing): "Mobile network operator (MNO)'s networks are overloaded."

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly leave the possessive out of the parenthetical. It is clearly understandable with the possessive used with the words.  (MNO) is fine.